# jQuery UI Tabs - content loaded by ajax doesn't scroll

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs, scroll

in INDEX.PHP
my tabs are declared as:

```
$(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
                load: function(event, ui) {
                    console.log("load event ran");
                    $('a', ui.panel).live("click", function() {
                           $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                           return false;
                           });
                   }

           });

        });
```

i have tabs liked to external php file to load content:

```
<div id="tabs">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="content.php?div=Production">Production</a></li>
              <li><a href="content.php?div=Digital">Digital</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

the forms on these pages are submitted by ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Search_form").validate({
            debug: false,
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.post('search_db.php', $("#Search_form").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('p.results').fadeIn();  
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

results are displayed within a tab, BUT browser doesn't create vertical scrolling bar to view the content that didn't fit in the browser window.

I understand this is s/t to do with multiple ajax functions inside each other, how can i force browser to review page content and create a scrollbar please?

P.S. I have only general understanding of jQuery and DOM functionality...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your css

```
.ui-tabs-panel {
     overflow:auto;
}
```

ps. sounds like your problem is only related to the stylesheet / styles and not jquery / script

Comment: i have already tried changing css to: .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-panel { display: block; border-width: 0; padding: 1em 1.4em; background: none; overflow: auto; } - this didn't work.

Comment: could you upload a screenshot or example on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: try fixing the height of the tab or adding   html { overflow-y: scroll; } its possible it is the page itself isn't scrolling

Comment: have never tried jsfiddle.net before and not sure what screenshoot would you like to see. here is browser screenshot: http://www.lcojc.org.uk/scr1.jpg

Comment: adding html { overflow-y: scroll; } did solve the problem. thanks!!! but it's still weird....